# How to add / remove parenthesis around a marked region in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I often find it is needed to  add / remove parenthesis / bracket around a marked region in Emacs.

Currently I do the adding manually by:

1. Move the cursor to one end of the intended region, type the opening deliminator;
2. Move the cursor to the other end of the intended region, type the closing deliminator;

And the removal in the other way around.

However, this seems cumbersome and error prone because of the movement of cursor. From a safety point of view, if I delete parenthesis in pairs, I feel safer, because it is an **atomic** operation

Is there a built-in or hand-crafted function in Emacs to do it with respect to marked region?

Comment: 1. I wonder why you *often* need to do that, because I almost never do. What is a scenario that leads you to this need? 2. Wrt cursor movement, I assume you know about `C-x C-x`, `C-M-f`, and `C-M-b`?

Comment: @Drew Hi, regarding your question: 1. E.g. When doing code review, I found someone added unnecessary parenthesis `((a + b))`. And I was tempted to remove them; 2. Yes I know these keys, but in the previous case, `((a + b))`. When I delete the outer opening `(`, I loses the convenience to jump to closing `)` right away.

Comment: @Drew  Also from a safety point of view, if I delete parenthesis in pairs, I feel safer. It is an **Atomic** operation.

Comment: The library yasnippet can enclose anything around a selected region -- I do this all the time when writing a LaTeX document and surround the selected region with codes like bold, center, italics, etc. -- see `yas/selected-text`  To remove, you could do something like `re-search-backward` / `re-search-forward` and delete the desired character.

Comment: A region also has a beginning and ending point -- `(region-beginning)` and `(region-end)`.  So, you could use those two points to add and remove parentheses.

Comment: @lawlist thx for the tips. I will spend sometime to try it out. As yet I am not familiar with elisp.

Comment: Use `C-SPC` and `C-x C-x` to define the region and bounce between its ends. After you delete or add a paren at one end, bounce to the other end to fix that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Removing a pair of surrounding characters (parens, brackets, whatever) with the `delete-pair` function:**
You don't have to mark the region.

- Before a pair: `M-x delete-pair`
- Inside a pair: `C-M-u` for backing out of the pair and then `M-x delete-pair`.
- Behind a pair: `M--` (negative argument) and then `M-x delete-pair`

**Enclosing a region with parens:**

- Marking the region and `M-(`.

Answer (score 1):

Try out these functions:

```
(defun surround-with-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (region-beginning))
    (insert "("))
  (goto-char (region-end))
  (insert ")"))

(defun delete-surrounded-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beginning (region-beginning))
        (end (region-end)))
    (cond ((not (eq (char-after beginning) ?\())
           (error "Character at region-begin is not an open-parenthesis"))
          ((not (eq (char-before end) ?\)))
           (error "Character at region-end is not a close-parenthesis"))
          ((save-excursion
             (goto-char beginning)
             (forward-sexp)
             (not (eq (point) end)))
           (error "Those parentheses are not matched"))
          (t (save-excursion
               (goto-char end)
               (delete-backward-char 1)
               (goto-char beginning)
               (delete-char 1))))))
```

The former inserts parentheses around the region, leaving point after the closing parenthesis.  The latter deletes parenthesis only if they are precisely<sup>*</sup> surrounded by the region, and if they are matched up correctly.

For instance, it will refuse to delete these parenthesis:

```
(x a b c d (y) z)
^            ^
this         and this
```

---

<sup>* This could be improved by searching inward for the parentheses rather than requiring that they be at the exact boundaries of the region; I'll do this later if I have time.</sup>

Comment: sorry bro, got to mark another ans as selected. But I liked other answers you made

Comment: @modeller Hey no worries!  I'm glad you said something because now I learned about the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(global-set-key "\M-'" 'insert-quotations)
(global-set-key "\M-\"" 'insert-quotes)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'insert-backquote)

(defun insert-quotations (&optional arg)
  "Enclose following ARG sexps in quotation marks.
Leave point after open-paren."
  (interactive "*P")
  (insert-pair arg ?\' ?\'))

(defun insert-quotes (&optional arg)
  "Enclose following ARG sexps in quotes.
Leave point after open-quote."
  (interactive "*P")
  (insert-pair arg ?\" ?\"))

(defun insert-backquote (&optional arg)
  "Enclose following ARG sexps in quotations with backquote.
Leave point after open-quotation."
  (interactive "*P")
  (insert-pair arg ?\` ?\'))
```

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertPair